# Sort a one dimensional array in ascending order using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`var array1 = [9,8,7,4,2];`

How do I sort this?
The output I am looking for is: `[2,4,7,8,9]`
Please help.

Comment: question title seems asking in only jquery.

Comment: This is a basic JavaScript function. Next time, just Google _"Sort JavaScript array"_, and one of your first results will be the [MDN on `Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**

```
var array1 = [9,8,7,4,2];

array1.sort();

console.log(array1); // [2,4,7,8,9]
```

But in your case, you can use **[reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)** as well:

```
var array1 = [9,8,7,4,2];

array1.reverse();

console.log(array1); // [2,4,7,8,9]
```

Comment: OP: Please note that `reverse()` doesn't apply any kind of sorting algorithm to the array. It just inverts it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work:

```
array1.sort();
```

If you want reverse, use:

```
array1.reverse();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C9CG5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array1.sort()`. Look here for more information http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp .